# Python Cartopy mapping

Tags: python, geospatial, cartopy

Im trying to map CO2 levels based on public data from NASA on global map and depict those values as (long,lat,value) as topographic map, based on the data and by using Panoply software, this is what my plot should look like:
[image]

The data is in .nc4 format and read correctly, however I cant get the data plot  **Im using Cartopy API & following this example:**(https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/gallery/waves.html#sphx-glr-gallery-waves-py).

**Also I do not want to use Basemap.**

**Attempt # 1:**

**See Python code below:**

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs


"""
function that download each OCO - 2 data that is in .nc4 format from file "subset_OCO2_L2_ABand_V8_20180929_010345.txt"
which is list of links
for all data with date range 2015 - 09 - 01 to 2016 - 01 - 01# make sure that you have a valid user name & password by registering in https: //earthdata.nasa.gov/
#implementation based on http: //unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section1"""

def download_oco2_nc4(username, password, filespath):
  filespath = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\oco2\\oco2_LtCO2_150831_B8100r_171009083146s.nc4"
  dataset = Dataset(filespath)
  print(dataset.file_format)
  print(dataset.dimensions.keys())
  print(dataset.variables['xco2'])
  XCO2 = []
  LONGITUDE = []
  LATITUDE = []
  # XCO2
  XCO2 = dataset.variables['xco2'][:]
  print("->", type(XCO2))
  print(dataset.variables['latitude'])
  # LATITUDE
  LATITUDE = dataset.variables['latitude'][:]
  print(dataset.variables['longitude'])
  # LONGITUDE
  LONGITUDE = dataset.variables['longitude'][:]
  return XCO2, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, dataset


def mapXoco2():
  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mollweide())

  XCO2, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, dataset = download_oco2_nc4(1, 2, 3)
  dataset.close()

  XCO2_subset = list()
  counter = 0
  for xco2 in XCO2:
      if counter < 10:
          XCO2_subset.append(xco2)
          counter = counter + 1
      else:
          break
  print("XCO2_subset="+str(len(XCO2_subset)))


  counter = 0
  LONGITUDE_subset = list()
  for longitude in LONGITUDE:
      if counter < 10:
          LONGITUDE_subset.append(longitude)
          counter = counter + 1
      else:
          break
  print("LONGITUDE_subset="+str(len(LONGITUDE_subset)))

  counter = 0
  LATITUDE_subset = list()
  for latitude in LATITUDE:
      if counter < 10:
          LATITUDE_subset.append(latitude)
          counter = counter + 1
      else:
          break
  print("LATITUDE_subset="+str(len(LATITUDE_subset)))

  XCO2_subset = np.array(XCO2_subset)
  LONGITUDE_subset = np.array(LONGITUDE_subset)
  LATITUDE_subset = np.array(LATITUDE_subset)
  #LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset = np.meshgrid(LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset)
  #XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset = np.meshgrid(XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset)
  ax.contourf(LONGITUDE_subset,LATITUDE_subset,XCO2_subset,
      transform = ccrs.Mollweide(central_longitude=0, globe=None),
      cmap = 'nipy_spectral')
  ax.coastlines()
  ax.set_global()
  plt.show()
  print(XCO2_subset)

mapXoco2()
```

**When I comment out these  lines:**

```
 #LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset = np.meshgrid(LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset)
      #XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset = np.meshgrid(XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset)
```

**I get an error:**

raise TypeError("Input z must be a 2D array.")

TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array.

**However when I DO NOT comment these lines:**

```
 LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset = np.meshgrid(LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset)
      XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset = np.meshgrid(XCO2_subset,XCO2_subset
```

)

I get an empty map, I see the continents but no plotted values C02 values.

I believe interpreting the 1D to 2D transformation  of my inputs incorrectly.

Attempt # 2(updated):

Instead of dealing with why/what these 2d transformations in the API are doing, Im ploting each point 1 by 1 using a loop. The issue is although I can see more data(Im only ploting about 10% of the data) **I CANT SEE THE MAP/CONTINENTS I SEE THE VALUES PLOT ON WHITE BACKGROUND???, SEE CODE:**

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from random import sample


"""
function that download each OCO - 2 data that is in .nc4 format from file "subset_OCO2_L2_ABand_V8_20180929_010345.txt"
which is list of links
for all data with date range 2015 - 09 - 01 to 2016 - 01 - 01# make sure that you have a valid user name & password by registering in https: //earthdata.nasa.gov/
#implementation based on http: //unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#section1"""

filespath = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\oco2_LtCO2_150830_B7305Br_160712072205s.nc4"

def download_oco2_nc4(filespath):

  dataset = Dataset(filespath)
  print("file format:"+str(dataset.file_format))
  print("dimensions.keys():"+str(dataset.dimensions.keys()))
  print("variables['xco2']:"+str(dataset.variables['xco2']))
  XCO2 = []
  LONGITUDE = []
  LATITUDE = []
  # XCO2
  XCO2 = dataset.variables['xco2'][:]
  print("->", type(XCO2))
  print(dataset.variables['latitude'])
  # LATITUDE
  LATITUDE = dataset.variables['latitude'][:]
  print(dataset.variables['longitude'])
  # LONGITUDE
  LONGITUDE = dataset.variables['longitude'][:]
  return XCO2, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, dataset


def mapXoco2():
  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 5))
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection = ccrs.Mollweide())

  XCO2, LONGITUDE, LATITUDE, dataset = download_oco2_nc4(filespath)
  dataset.close()


  XCO2_subset = np.array(XCO2)
  LONGITUDE_subset = np.array(LONGITUDE)
  LATITUDE_subset = np.array(LATITUDE)

  """each of the arrays has over 80,000 of data therefore its taking to long to map, after 10,000 rows its to slow, and 10,000 isnt sufficient. 
  Because oco-2 gathers data from trajectory the 1st 10% or whatever precent of the data will not be a good representation of the overal data. 
  We must sample from X number of  slices across the data.
  """
  #XCO2 attempt to get ten ranges, we need to check 10 ranges therefore we need if statements not if/else
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=10000):
      first_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[0:1000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=20000):
      second_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[20000:21000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=30000):
      third_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[30000:31000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=40000):
      fourth_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[40000:41000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=50000):
      fifth_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[50000:51000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=60000):
      sixth_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[60000:61000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=70000):
      seventh_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[70000:71000]
  if (len(XCO2_subset)>=80000):
      eight_XCO2_subset=XCO2_subset[80000:81000]


  sampled_xco2 = first_XCO2_subset + second_XCO2_subset + third_XCO2_subset + fourth_XCO2_subset +  fifth_XCO2_subset + sixth_XCO2_subset + seventh_XCO2_subset +  eight_XCO2_subset

    #LONGITUDE attempt to get ten ranges, we need to check 10 ranges therefore we need if statements not if/else
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=10000):
      first_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[0:1000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=20000):
      second_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[20000:21000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=30000):
      third_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[30000:31000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=40000):
      fourth_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[40000:41000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=50000):
      fifth_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[50000:51000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=60000):
      sixth_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[60000:61000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=70000):
      seventh_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[70000:71000]
  if (len(LONGITUDE_subset)>=80000):
      eight_LONGITUDE_subset=LONGITUDE_subset[80000:81000]

  sampled_LONGITUDE = first_LONGITUDE_subset + second_LONGITUDE_subset + third_LONGITUDE_subset + fourth_LONGITUDE_subset +  fifth_LONGITUDE_subset + sixth_LONGITUDE_subset + seventh_LONGITUDE_subset +  eight_LONGITUDE_subset
  #LATITUDE attempt to get ten ranges, we need to check 10 ranges therefore we need if statements not if/else
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=10000):
      first_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[0:1000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=20000):
      second_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[20000:21000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=30000):
      third_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[30000:31000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=40000):
      fourth_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[40000:41000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=50000):
      fifth_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[50000:51000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=60000):
      sixth_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[60000:61000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=70000):
      seventh_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[70000:71000]
  if (len(LATITUDE_subset)>=80000):
      eight_LATITUDE_subset=LATITUDE_subset[80000:81000]

  sampled_LATITUDE = first_LATITUDE_subset + second_LATITUDE_subset + third_LATITUDE_subset + fourth_LATITUDE_subset +  fifth_LATITUDE_subset + sixth_LATITUDE_subset + seventh_LATITUDE_subset +  eight_LATITUDE_subset

  ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mollweide())
  #plt.contourf(LONGITUDE_subset, LATITUDE_subset, XCO2_subset, 60,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
  for long, lat, value in zip(sampled_LONGITUDE, sampled_LATITUDE,sampled_xco2):
    #print(long, lat, value)
    if value >= 0 and value < 370:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='blue', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    elif value >= 370 and value < 390:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='cyan', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    elif value >= 390 and value < 402:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='yellow', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    elif value >= 402 and value < 410:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='orange', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    elif value >= 410 and value < 415:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='red', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    else:
        ax.plot(long,lat,marker='o',color='brown', markersize=1, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

  ax.coastlines()
  plt.show()


mapXoco2()
```

**Output:**

file format:NETCDF4

dimensions.keys():odict_keys(['sounding_id', 'levels', 'bands', 'vertices', 'epoch_dimension', 'source_files'])

variables['xco2']:
float32 xco2(sounding_id)
    units: ppm
    long_name: XCO2
    missing_value: -999999.0
    comment: Column-averaged dry-air mole fraction of CO2 (includes bias correction)

unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (82776,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

-> 

float32 latitude(sounding_id)
    units: degrees_north
    long_name: latitude
    missing_value: -999999.0
    comment: center latitude of the measurement
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (82776,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

float32 longitude(sounding_id)
    units: degrees_east
    long_name: longitude
    missing_value: -999999.0
    comment: center longitude of the measurement
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (82776,)
filling on, default _FillValue of 9.969209968386869e+36 used

[image]

**1) What happened to the map & continents?**

Thanks & any useful help appreciated.

Comment: You only need to change the transform to `PlateCarree()`, you can leave the projection as `Mollweide()`. Please see https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html as suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your transform argument is incorrect. If you have latitude/longitude data the value of the transform argument should be `ccrs.PlateCarree()`. See this guide in the cartopy documentation for details: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/tutorials/understanding_transform.html.

Comment: @Thanks, I actually uploaded  all the script so its is runnable however  I cannot upload the nc4 due to its size.

Comment: @adjawson,  can you look at my attempt # 2, its missing the map?